# Converting "flat" csv data to table with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, import

I have a CSV file of employee hours.  Each row contains a column for the employee, date, and hours.  An example would be:

```
Employee,Date,Hours
A,2015-01-02,10
A,2015-01-03,8
A,2015-01-04,5
B,2015-01-02,8
B,2015-01-03,2
C,2015-01-03,8
C,2015-01-04,8
```

What I am looking for is a Pandas data frame, where the row index is the date, and each column is an employee, and the data is the number of hours e.g.:

```
Date         A     B     C
2015-01-02   10    8     None
2015-01-03   8     2     8
2015-01-04   5     None  8
```

Perhaps I am searching for the wrong terms, but is there an easy way within pandas to do such a conversion on import of the csv file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After loading your csv using `read_csv` like so: `df = pd.read_csv(file_path)` you can then use [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot) and pass the columns Employee and Date as the columns and index respectively:

```
In [91]:

df.pivot(columns='Employee', index='Date')
Out[91]:
           Hours        
Employee       A   B   C
Date                    
2015-01-02    10   8 NaN
2015-01-03     8   2   8
2015-01-04     5 NaN   8
```